# Modify a Vendor Migration in Laravel

Tags: laravel, uuid, multi-tenant, voyager

I'm attempting to use UUID's for my user ID's in Laravel and to support this I need to modify a vendor migration (in this case the Voyager admin panel) to change the user id type.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Usually, you should not modify files in the vendor folder; this does not seem to be the way.

Comment: @AlexandreStrapacaoG.Vianna correct and I don't want to, so surely there must be a way to ignore the vendor migration and replace it with my own without modification of a vendor file?

Comment: I understand. I think when using Voyager, you end up losing the ability to make such customizations.
If you don't find any solution, depending on the case, you can actually change the voyager's code by taking care of the maintenance problems. It is up to you to assess the cost-effectiveness.
In the meantime, you leave a suggestion for improvement for the Voyager folks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create this type of migration file: https://github.com/laravel/fortify/blob/1.x/database/migrations/2014_10_12_200000_add_two_factor_columns_to_users_table.php

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps in the context of my question? I know how to create a migration file. What I want to do is ignore a vendor migration in favour of my own.

Comment: If you read the code carefully, you can see it that this is not a migration file to create a table. It's modifying an existing table. So you can add column, remıove column or update column. I don't know what else you want to do.